# "Operating System Concepts": Busy waiting is not eliminated with semaphore?

Tags: operating-system, semaphore

Why the busy waiting is not eliminated even after we put the current process into the process list and "block()"ed it? So even if the process is in waiting state we still call it "busy waiting"?

I'm reading *Operating System Concepts, Silberschatz, 9th ed., pages 215~217.*

[image: highlighted part]

[image: sema1]

[image: sema2]

Comment: I suspect that you misunderstand or, just as likely, the book text is not very clear about the explanation. The 'busy-waiting' referred to is a small, critical section within the semaphore implementation itself and, since it only protects the semaphore count, it's always very short, so greatly reducing the chances of contention anyway.  The user threads that make signal/wait calls are not aware of this internal critical section and any, very short, busy-wait in the calls has little impact on the semaphore operations. If a thread calls wait() on an empty semaphore, it WILL block efficiently.

Comment: @MartinJames: I found a slide online says the implementation, which is the same as I provided, is the "non busying waiting version", so maybe it's not my misunderstanding. By the way could you please help me on another question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51571596/5290519, so I can improve the question?

Comment: Here is the slide: https://www.coursehero.com/file/p15f97j/Semaphore-Implementation-with-no-Busy-Waiting-Semaphore-Implementation-with-no/